# Task Scheduler doesn't work when my Python 3.6 script has the requests module imported into it.

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have the following .py file scheduled in task scheudler:

```
import time

print ("hello world")
time.sleep(10)
print ("hello world 2")
```

It seems to run fine in task scheduler. However, as soon as I import other modules like requests or pyodbc or tweepy like so:

```
import time
import requests

print ("hello world")
time.sleep(10)
print ("hello world 2")
```

the script doesn't run. It seems that it crashes when it tries to import requests. Why is this? Is there a way around this error?

I'm using Windows 10 64bit

Comment: the extra modules may be not importable from the task scheduler environement. Add this to the begining of your script: `import sys; print(sys.path)` and check that folder where request is installed is part of the output.

Comment: I tried that. The same thing happens. The command window comes up and then immediately dissapears. When I used Windows 7 and Python 2.6, everything worked fine :S

Comment: Then add a time.sleep(60) after the print to give you time to read the output

Comment: Okay now this prints :

['C:\\Users\\lidauser\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Current', 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: and if you do `import requests; print(requests.__file__)` in your interpreter, what do you get ? Is that a file from one of the directories above ?

Answer (score 1):

Late response but hopefully it helps someone.

I had the same issue but for another module (pyautogui). I had the *Program/Script* for my task as just `python` originally and the *"Add arguments (optional)"* field was the path to my file. I found out that the version of Python that Task Scheduler was running was different than the one that ran when I typed `python file.py` in command prompt.
So

1. I'm assuming you can run your script normally with Python with command prompt and it works. Find the location of the python.exe that runs when you run Python like that (just `import sys` and then print `sys.path`)
2. Change the *Program/Script* to be the path to that exe (e.g. `C:\Python36\python.exe`), keeping your *Argument* field the same as before (the path to your Python file you want to run.)

If no luck, then make sure you `pip -r install requirements.txt` outside of your venv if you're using one, since Task Scheduler's Python won't have access to those.

If that doesn't work you can also try switching from "Run whether user is logged on or not" to "Run only when user is logged on" and checkmark "Run with highest privileges".